# How to fix package not directly in apt cache after starting ubuntu22.04 instance?

Tags: ansible, apt

After starting a cloud instance, different packages are installed using an ansible playbook. This works when accessing the instance remotely, but when I access it via my program directly, just after creating the instance, it fails, because it can't find a standard package: `No package matching 'docker.io' is available`. As implied above, it has no issues finding the package when I then connect to the instance and manually repeat the command (i.e. run said playbook).

I tested whether the package is in the apt-cache by using `apt-cache show docker.io` and apparently it is not. This confuses me a little since I don't understand how it can magically appear later. But this explains why ansible is unable to find it since it just takes a look in the cache:

```
TASK [common : Install Docker] *************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/playbook/roles/common/tasks/030-docker.yml:1
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible/modules/apt.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ghkszxgwpyzhztutyejukfzkeokujykh ; /usr/bin/python3'"'"' && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_apt_payload_n4snw4g0/ansible_apt_payload.zip/ansible/modules/apt.py", line 511, in package_status
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 283, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_change_held_packages": false,
            "allow_downgrade": false,
            "allow_unauthenticated": false,
            "autoclean": false,
            "autoremove": false,
            "cache_valid_time": 0,
            "clean": false,
            "deb": null,
            "default_release": null,
            "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold",
            "fail_on_autoremove": false,
            "force": false,
            "force_apt_get": false,
            "install_recommends": null,
            "lock_timeout": 60,
            "name": "docker.io",
            "only_upgrade": false,
            "package": [
                "docker.io"
            ],
            "policy_rc_d": null,
            "purge": false,
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": null,
            "update_cache_retries": 5,
            "update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12,
            "upgrade": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "No package matching 'docker.io' is available"
}
```

The path to a solution might therefore be to understand why the cache is not ready yet and add a command before executing ansible or in ansible that updates the cache properly.

**Additional info**

The specific task is:

```
- name: Install Docker
  apt:
    name: docker.io
    state: present
  tags: install
```

The distribution in use is **ubuntu22.04**

**Commands run before ansible**

Before installing packages via ansible, I deactivate automatic updating and upgrading, wait till the lock is released, update and do a simple ping command via ansible (that runs without issues).

Deactivating automatic updating:

```
sudo sed -i 's/APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";/APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Wait till lock is released:

```
while sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock 2> null; do echo "/var/lib/dpkg/lock locked - wait for 10 seconds"; sleep 10; done
```

Ping:

```
ansible -i "~/playbook/ansible_hosts" all -m ping
```

**EDIT 3**

When testing I noticed that adding a 20 second update between ping and execution, the error mentioned above does not occur (at least in the test runs i did). So I think it is probably a timing issue. Any idea what to wait for?

Comment: How do you install it via Ansible? Ad-hoc command? Playbook? Else? Please provide  that in an [edit] of your question.

Comment: I updated the question and added that I run a playbook

Comment: Ok, now, mind that `docker.io` is an old beast and might not be part of more recent distributions anymore, what is the distribution and version your are trying to install it on?

Comment: I added that ubuntu22.04 is the distribution in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know why the `apt update` before is not enough, adding `update_cache: 'yes'` fixed it:

```
- name: Install Docker
  apt:
    name: docker.io
    state: present
    update_cache: 'yes'
  tags: install
```